# MongoDB BI connector for Mac M-chip?

Tags: mongodb, odbc

The latest version available for download (1.4.3) appears to incorporate components that use x-86 architecture, and it will not run on my new Mac.

The error is

ODBC Error: [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/Library/MongoDB/ODBC/1.4.3/libmdbodbca.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Library/MongoDB/ODBC/1.4.3/libmdbodbca.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
[iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded

The only advice I get from Mongodb support is to "run it under Rosetta" but I have no idea which piece of software to force to run this way.

OR, is it possible to use the Oracle MySQL driver instead? (Is there is an article explaining how to set that up ...?)